# Problemas al Obtener diferencia de fechas con javascript

Tags: javascript, momentjs

Saludos estoy comparando fechas con javascript pero solo toma en cuenta los dias no toma en cuenta el año ni el mes de que manera puedo poner que se compare tomando en cuenta todo dia mes y año actualmente lo tengo asi :

```
   if (FechaRecibo.getDate()  > FechaActual.getDate() ) {
                    debugger

                    swal("", "the arrival date can not be longer than the current date", "warning");

                }
```

Answer (score 1):

Si estás usando momentjs y `FechaRecibo` y `FechaActual` son objetos moment, entonces, para comparar y entrar en la función es:

```
if(FechaRecibo.isAfter(FechaActual)) {
 ...
}
```

Comment: Gracias me sirvio

Comment: @user116475 no olvides dar por válida la respuesta, por favor